# get table name in Postgres query result

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to get table name in query result. The query I am trying to do involves multiple table. This is why I am trying to get a column with result which will indicate from which table the data taken from. Here is the code I am using

```
(SELECT DISTINCT column_1 as keywords from table_1) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT DISTINCT column_2 as keywords from table_2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_1 AS keywords, 'table_1' AS tablename
FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT column_2 AS keywords, 'table_2' AS tablename
FROM table_2
```

It adds one more column `tablename` to result set, which contains originating table name.