# Get the name of a row's source table when querying the parent it inherits from

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance

I have a Postgres database with several tables that inherit from one other. I can `SELECT` from the parent table to get results from all it's children, but need to get the name of the table that each result originates from.

The method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016549/get-table-name-in-postgres-query-result) does not work since I am only querying the one table, and do not know which children will be in the results ahead of time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To identify the source table of a particular row, use the [**`tableoid`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html), like you found yourself already.
A cast to [**`regclass`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) retrieves the actual name, automatically schema-qualified where needed according to the current `search_path`.

```
SELECT *, tableoid::regclass::text AS table_name
FROM   master.tbl
WHERE  <some_condition>;
```

More:

- [Find out which schema based on table values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902072/find-out-which-schema-based-on-table-values/12902441#12902441)
- [Select (retrieve) all records from multiple schemas using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575610/retrieve-all-records-from-multiple-schemas-in-a-postgresql-database/20576324#20576324)
- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Comment: Not too interested in the schema right now, but the casting is a nice idea. Shortens the query a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the PostgreSQL documentation, in the [section on inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html). One can use the hidden `tableoid` column of the table along with `relname` from `pg_class` to add a column containing the table names to the result, as shown:

```
SELECT t.*, p.relname FROM table t, pg_class p WHERE t.tableoid = p.oid;
```