# Include table name in RETURNING from INSERT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-returning

I have an `INSERT` statement like so that returns the inserted IDs:

```
INSERT INTO encyclopedias (page_id)
SELECT page.id FROM pages
RETURNING id;

INSERT INTO cookbooks (page_id)
SELECT page.id FROM pages
RETURNING id;
```

Which returns something like:

```
 id 
----
1
2

 id 
----
3
4
```

When parsing the output, I'd like tell which table the IDs are from, like either:

```
encyclopedia id
----
1
2

cookbook id
----
3
4
```

or:

```
table, id
----
encyclopedias, 1
encyclopedias, 2

table, id
----
cookbooks, 3
cookbooks, 4
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple solution to automate this using the system column [**`tableoid`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html).

That's the internal OID (object ID) of the source table, which can be cast to `regclass` to convert it to the actual table name.

```
INSERT INTO encyclopedias (page_id)
SELECT id FROM pages
RETURNING tableoid::regclass::text AS table, page_id AS id;
```

Returns your desired output exactly:

```
table         | id
--------------+----
encyclopedias | 1
encyclopedias | 2
```

If you change the table in the `FROM` clause (like in your example), you don't need to adapt the `RETURNING` clause.

Related:

- [Get the name of a row's source table when querying the parent it inherits from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580352/get-the-name-of-a-rows-source-table-when-querying-the-parent-it-inherits-from/24581769#24581769)

Answer (score 2):

Use column aliases and constants in the `returning` clause:

```
insert into t(x) values(1) returning x as xx, 'the table' as table_name;
╔════╤════════════╗
║ xx │ table_name ║
╠════╪════════════╣
║  1 │ the table  ║
╚════╧════════════╝
```

Upd:

Additionally you can to specify several output format settings for the psql, for example:

```
$ echo "
> \pset format unaligned
> \pset tuples_only on
> \echo --==## foo ##==--
> select 1,2,3;" | psql
Output format is unaligned.
Tuples only is on.
--==## foo ##==--
1|2|3
```

Find more in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do that is by using the `WITH` queries:

```
WITH inserts AS (
INSERT INTO encyclopedias (page_id)
SELECT page.id FROM pages
RETURNING id
)
SELECT inserts.id AS encyclopedia_id;
```

or

```
WITH inserts AS (
INSERT INTO encyclopedias (page_id)
SELECT page.id FROM pages
RETURNING id
)
SELECT 'encyclopedia' AS "table", inserts.id AS "id";
```

More information on the [PostgreSQL Documentation page about INSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-insert.html)

Comment: That's sneaky sticking an INSERT into a CTE like that. Very nice!

Comment: @JNevill: A CTE does not help here. It only makes the query more expensive and complicated.