# Get child table names in Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a base table

```
CREATE TABLE base_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

And two child tables that inherit from it

```
CREATE TABLE child_a (
  description TEXT
) INHERITS (base_table);

CREATE TABLE child_b (
  age INT
) INHERITS (base_table);
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return all of the fields from the base table and all of its children but also append the name of each row's 'parent' table to the results.

So far, I can get all the other fields I need with

```
SELECT id, description, age
FROM ONLY base_table
NATURAL FULL JOIN child_a
NATURAL FULL JOIN child_b
```

I'm a little stumped on how to include the parent table name in the results. I'd like the results to be something like

```
Id, Description,      Age,   TableName
---------------------------------------
1   TestDescription   null   child_a
2   null              10     child_b
3   OtherDescription  null   child_a
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn’t that a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/24581769/1222135 ?

Comment: Almost a duplicate, there is a subtle difference however. Thanks @greg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subqueries instead of child tables:

```
SELECT id, description, age, coalesce(t1, t2) as tablename
FROM base_table
NATURAL FULL JOIN (
    SELECT *, 'child_a'::text AS t1
    FROM child_a
    ) a
NATURAL FULL JOIN (
    SELECT *, 'child_b'::text AS t2
    FROM child_b
    ) b;

 id |   description    | age | tablename 
----+------------------+-----+-----------
  1 | TestDescription  |     | child_a
  2 |                  |  10 | child_b
  3 | OtherDescription |     | child_a
(3 rows)
```

---

Update. There is a nice solution described [in ths answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24581769/1995738). To use it in this case you have to explicitly specify a base_table for a [system column `tableoid:`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html)

```
SELECT *, base_table.tableoid::regclass::text AS table_name
FROM base_table
FULL JOIN child_a USING(id)
FULL JOIN child_b USING(id);
```