# SELECT value depending on underlying table name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to set the value of a column based on the table being queried.

Example:

Let's assume two tables: `Transportation` and `Locations`. And a `SELECT` statement with a column named `type` which shall hold 'Transportation' or 'Locations' based on the table being queried. Is there a way to do this? Maybe something similar to a "RegEx lookahead"?

Comment: Do you have a draft of the query? Seeing the `FROM` clause would help an awful lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`tableoid`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) is the way to go, like Adam already suggested.

But this is faster and safer:

```
SELECT CASE t.tableoid WHEN 'transportation'::regclass THEN 'Transportation'
                       WHEN 'locations'::regclass      THEN 'Locations'
                       ELSE 'Unknown' END AS type
FROM   some_table t;
```

This way we only cast said tables to *oid* once - instead of two casts for every row. Plus, comparing OIDs (4-byte integer internally) is cheaper than `text`. Around 10x faster in a quick test on Postgres 12.

Schema-qualify the table names if there can be ambiguity:

```
SELECT CASE t.tableoid WHEN 'public.transportation'::regclass THEN 'Transportation'
                       WHEN 'public.locations'::regclass      THEN 'Locations' ...
```

Else you depend on the current `search_path` of the session:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

If you actually use mixed-case names like the spelling in the question suggests, you have to add double-quotes:

```
SELECT CASE t.tableoid WHEN 'public."Transportation"'::regclass THEN 'Transportation'
                       WHEN 'public."Locations"'::regclass      THEN 'Locations' ...
```

See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

If said tables might not exist, you risk an error from the cast. You can prevent that using `to_regclass()` instead:

```
SELECT CASE t.tableoid WHEN to_regclass('transportation') THEN 'Transportation'
                       WHEN to_regclass('locations')      THEN 'Locations' ...
```

But the function is more costly than the plain cast. See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

None of this seems actually *necessary* for your use case. You have to adapt the table name in the `FROM` clause anyway, you can just do the same for the expression in the `SELECT` clause.
With inheritance or partitioning it can actually be essential, though. See:

- [Get the name of a row's source table when querying the parent it inherits from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580352/get-the-name-of-a-rows-source-table-when-querying-the-parent-it-inherits-from/24581769#24581769)

Answer (score 1):

Use `tableoid`, casting to regclass and then to text.

```
testdb=# create table transportation(c text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# create table locations(c text);
CREATE TABLE
testdb=# insert into transportation select 'foo';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# insert into locations select 'bar';
INSERT 0 1
testdb=# select c, CASE WHEN tableoid::regclass::text='transportation' then 'Transportation' when tableoid::regclass::text='locations' then 'Locations' else 'Unknown' end as "type" from locations /* transportation */;
  c  |   type    
-----+-----------
 bar | Locations
(1 row)

testdb=# select c, CASE WHEN tableoid::regclass::text='transportation' then 'Transportation' when tableoid::regclass::text='locations' then 'Locations' else 'Unknown' end as "type" from /*locations */ transportation ;
  c  |      type      
-----+----------------
 foo | Transportation
(1 row)
```

[More information on tableoid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-system-columns.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is usually handled through `left join`s, with judicious use of `coalesce()`:

```
select o.*, coalesce(t.name, l.name) as name
from originaltable o left join
     transportation t
     on t.transportation_id = o.combined_id and o.type = 'T' left join
     locations l
     on l.location_id = o.combined_id and o.type = 'L'
```